# what is a collapse of a state vector or wave function?

Tags: quantum-entanglement

I read there are two kinds of explanations on the "collapse of a state vector or wave function".

1) for an arbitrary state vector $|x\rangle=\sum\alpha_n|\phi_n\rangle$

after measurement, $|x\rangle\rightarrow|\phi_k\rangle$, where $\phi_k$ is particular eigenvector.

here the superposition state $\sum\alpha_n|\phi_n\rangle$ is collapsed to a particular eigenvector $|\phi_k\rangle$ with probability $P_k=\alpha_k\alpha_k^\ast$

2) in double slit experiment,

$|o\rangle\rightarrow|\mathrm {up\_slit}\rangle+|\mathrm{down\_slit}\rangle\rightarrow\sum\alpha_n|\phi_n\rangle+\sum\beta_n|\phi_n\rangle=\sum(\alpha_n+\beta_n)|\phi_n\rangle$

after measurement on the screen,

$P_k=(\alpha_k+\beta_k)(\alpha_k^\ast+\beta_k^\ast)=\alpha_k\alpha_k^\ast+\alpha_k\beta_k^\ast+\beta_k\alpha_k^\ast+\beta_k\beta_k^\ast$

but if put a spin to detect the two slits, then the system will form an entanglement, resulting in

$|o\rangle\rightarrow|\mathrm {up\_slit},u\rangle+|\mathrm {down\_slit},d\rangle\rightarrow\sum\alpha_n|\phi_n,u\rangle+\sum\beta_n|\phi_n,d\rangle$

in this case,

$P_k=(\sum\alpha_n^\ast\langle\phi_n,u|+\sum\beta_n^\ast\langle\phi_n,d|)(|\phi_k,u\rangle\langle\phi_k,u|+|\phi_k,d\rangle\langle\phi_k,d|)(\sum\alpha_n|\phi_n,u\rangle+\sum\beta_n|\phi_n,d\rangle)=\alpha_k\alpha_k^\ast+\beta_k\beta_k^\ast$

here the interference items like $\alpha_k\beta_k^\ast+\beta_k\alpha_k^\ast$ vanish away. In some teaching, it is also called wave function collapse.

My question is: Obviously these are two different kinds of collapse, which one is the right? or maybe both are right in different context?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the question only concerns terminology. I have not seen the second point you mention called "wave function collapse" before, only the first one. It would be nice if you could provide a reference, which may help clarify this point.

Comment: I don't get your 'two' types of collapse. When a state vector collapses upon measuremenyt, it is always to one of its eigenstates is it not? Some texts state this as a postulate even. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I searched on the internet, the second case is called "interference pattern collapse", instead of "wave function collapse", in terms of the terminology. thanks.